# Can i use a single AWS account for multiple websites which need SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simple-email-service

We are a growing agency and we like to use SES to improve deliverability for emails that get generated by client websites.

The agency has an AWS account which uses SES and we would now like to add in another website. However, despite the fact you can verify multiple domains, it looks like SES can only be used with a single website.

In SES home, under the 'your account details' section it has the web address and no way of adding another.

Do i need to create a new AWS account for every client we want to use SES with?

Comment: Have you tried seeting up [from email](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html)?

Comment: you should be able to use it with multiple domains. you need to verify the domains individually. after that: how are you sending the emails? smtp or aws sdk?